# Display content having the taxonomy of the logged in user

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I need help creating a view in Drupal 7 with the following logic:

- My users have taxonomy reference field.
- My articles also have    taxonomy reference field.

**When a user is logged in I want them to see only the articles that have the same term as the logged in user.**  How to set the relationships and contextual filters in this view?

Answer (score 0):

Create a view to display the article content, then add as relation for user and  add a contextual filter for UID for logged in user.

Add new filter for content taxonomy and it must be equal to user taxonomy.

Comment: Hi Prem, thanks for your answer. I don't understand this part "add as relation for user". When I click the "Add" button of the "Relationships" section, which one should I select? The only one that mentions "user" is called "Content revision: User" but I don't think this is the one I need.