# Contextual views - show articles that the current user is interested in

Tags: 8, views

### Aim

I am working on a Drupal 8 site that has articles which have a 'interests' field, and each User profile has a 'interests' field.

**I want to create a view that only shows articles that the currently logged in user is interested in.** For example, if the currently logged in user is interested in "Sports" and "Business", the view should show all articles that are tagged as either "Sports" or "Business".

### Attempts

I presume that the solution will involve using Relationships and Contextful Filters. I have read about both [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1578558) and [here](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/how-to-use-contextual-filters-in-drupal-8/).

I have checked previous answers, and think this one is pretty close to what I'm trying to do: [Display content having the taxonomy of the logged in user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185228/display-content-having-the-taxonomy-of-the-logged-in-user)

However, I couldn't seem to get it to work for Drupal 8

### Amends

Include of screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 2):

### 1) Create users View

[image]

### 2) Add contextual filter of User ID

[image]

### 3) a) Add relationship of reference field

[image]

### 3) b) Checkmark require this relationship

[image]

### 4) a) Add relationship of Content with term

[image]

### 4) b) Checkmark require this relationship

[image]

### 5) Now in FIELDS it should allow you to add title field

[image]

### 6) Remove Name from fields.

### 7) Add FILTER CRITERIA of Published content

[image]

[image]

### Overall, should look like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you @No Sssweat
So the thread below won't solve the problem without custom code?https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2011-03-31/solved-views-filtering-nodes-by-current-user-profile

Comment: @Darcy I take that back, added a solution based on that link.

Comment: thank you for that! Unfortunately, I'm not getting any results populating on on the view page (even though articles nodes are generated with the relevant tags are generated). 

Coud it be because the user profile is using field_interests and the article is using field_event_category? 

Should I be using 'Add relationships: 'Content using field_event_category' instead?

Comment: @Darcy nope needs to be using field interest relationship. Can you provide a screenshot of your View's settings? Maybe you did something wrong.

Comment: I have included a screenshot in the original question for your reference! :)

Comment: @Darcy Possible causes, make sure you're hitting the right path, you set it to `suggested-events-test-` ending with a `-` for some reason, which is odd. For testing purposes, you could keep it simple and change it `hello` and then go to `/hello`. Also make sure you set a default value the same as [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkBeW.png) for step 2. If still no dice, remove the published filter. If still nothing, go to `/user` and then click on "edit" and make sure you did set a value in the interests field. Lastly, make sure that there are articles tagged with same terms as user.